# PowerApps-Canvas: Unable to use DependsOn functionality of the DropDown component

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a 3 tables as following:

[image: Table relationships]

Over here, In canvas app, I wanted to set a dependant drop down fields, where based on a selected location, Bin dropdown should be filtered.

I have tried below PowerFx function but it seems not working.

```
Filter('Item Master', Bin.'Bin Name' = First(Filter('Item Master',"Warehouse" = Location.'Location Name')).Bin.'Bin Name')
```

The formula does not show any error, but just a warning as below on 1st equal sign and last :
Delegation warning. The filter part of this formula might not work correctly on large data sets.

[image: PowerFx formula screenhot]

**Any suggestion for this issue? How can I make this "Bin" dependant on the selected "Location"?**

**EDIT 1**:

I have found some related videos but seems it does not fulfil my requirements as it supports only single lookup field.

Here's the reference for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWEQwGLcW7Q

Comment: How many records are in Bin?
Can you use the built-in dependant drop-down - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists

Comment: @HSS, Not much, hardly 50 for now...
And already tried a dependent dropdown, but options does not appear based on what my requirement and data structure is.